# Why can't I create {a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c} from x={a,b,c}; f={3,5,2}; Thread@Table[x,f]?

Tags: list-manipulation, evaluation, iterators

```
ClearAll[x, f]
x = {a, b, c};
f = {3, 5, 2};
Thread[Table[x, f]]
```

produces

> Table::nliter: Non-list iterator f at position 2 does not evaluate to
> a real numeric value.
>
> `Table[x, f]`

Why can't I create `{a,a,a,b,b,b,b,b,c,c}` from `x={a,b,c}; f={3,5,2}; Thread@Table[x,f]`?

However, the following is fine!

```
ClearAll[x, f]
x = {a, b, c};
f = {3, 5, 2};
MapThread[Table, {x, f}]
```

Note: `//Flatten` at the end is intentionally removed for simplicity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is an evaluation order issue.

- `x` and `f` need to expand (evaluate) to `{a, b, c}` and `{3, 5, 2}` for `Thread` to work
- `Table` has attribute [`HoldAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) which prevents its arguments form evaluating first
- Specific evaluation of `Table` (before `Thread`) should be suppressed to avoid warning messages

Holding `Table` gets around each of these points:

```
x = {a, b, c};
f = {3, 5, 2};

Thread[Hold[Table][x, f]] // ReleaseHold
```

> ```
> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b, b, b}, {c, c}}
> ```

Similarly using [`Inactive`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactive.html)/[`Activate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Activate.html):

```
Thread[Inactive[Table][x, f]] // Activate
```

> ```
> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b, b, b}, {c, c}}
> ```

But it is usually easier to [`Apply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) afterward:

```
Table @@@ Thread[{x, f}]
```

> ```
> {{a, a, a}, {b, b, b, b, b}, {c, c}}
> ```

Consider also [`Inner`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inner.html)

```
Inner[Table, x, f, Join]
```

> ```
> {a, a, a, b, b, b, b, b, c, c}
> ```